# Recover my SD Card

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, sd-card, diskpart

In windows disk mgr I can see this. I have no option to shrink/expand any of the partitions.
[image]

Tried to delelete everything by DISKPART, but that's also not working:

```
DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          111 GB  1024 KB
  Disk 1    Online         7535 MB      0 B

DISKPART> SELECT DISK 1

The disk you specified is not valid.

There is no disk selected.

DISKPART>
```

How can I recover my sd card?

Comment: I'm not sure. ext4 maybe.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recover my SD Card](http://superuser.com/questions/836299/recover-my-sd-card)

Answer (score 0):

BOOTICE solved my issue. You can re-partitionate anything with it. http://bbs.ipauly.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2